# How many machine cycles does the HLT instruction require on the intel 8085?

Tags: assembly, architecture, instructions, 8085

I have referred the Intel 8085 manual, it says that the HLT instruction requires **1 machine cycle and 5 or more T states**, but my textbook and some internet sources say that it requires **2 machines cycles and the number of T states can vary depending on if there are any pending interrupts or not**. Clarify this please

I guess since it is a 1 byte instruction, the only bus operation it performs is the opcode fetch,thus 1 M cycle but am not sure about how many T states it should require.....

Comment: The textbook I am reading is: Microprocessor Architecture, Programming and applications with the 8085 by Ramesh Gaonkar

Comment: Just curious why you care?  It seems odd to be concerned about the exact number of cycles needed by `hlt`, given that its whole point is to wait for a potentially very long time.  You would only execute it if your code has nothing else useful to be doing.

Comment: Disagreement in timings information may be caused by different interpretation of "instruction requires" meaning. Since `hlt` waits for external interrupt, it requires some number of cycles to put CPU into halt state and some other number of cycles to wake up CPU after interrupt occured.

Comment: So that means there is no definite number of M cycles for the HLT instruction? should I just go by the manual and write 1 M cycle in all the assembly program documentation that I have to do for college?